# Одушевлённость шахматных фигур

Tags: существительные

Являются ли слова вроде `ферзь` одушевлёнными?

С одной стороны, `ферзь` отвечает на вопрос "что", а не "кто".

С другой, склоняется это существительное, по крайней мере в ед. ч., как одушевлённое: `потерял ферзя`, а не `потерял ферзь`.

А во множественном числе с числительным?  Как правильно: `потерять два ферзя` или `потерять двух ферзей`? `Потерять две пешки/ладьи` или `потерять двух пешек/ладей`?

И есть ли разница со слонами и конями?  Потерять два слона или потерять двух слонов?

Такое впечатление, что шахматные фигуры обладают свойствами и одушевлённых, и неодушевлённых существительных. И к тому же свойства разные для разных фигур. По-моему:

- пешка и ладья - полностью неодушевленные: отвечают на вопрос "что", с числительными ведут себя как неодушевленные, склонение в единственном числе не зависит от одушевленности
- король, ферзь, слон, конь - обладают смесью признаков одушевленных и неодушевленных существительных: отвечают на вопрос "что", с числительными ведут себя и так, и так, склонение в единственном числе как у одушевленных

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Являются ли слова вроде ферзь одушевлёнными?

*пешка, ладья* are inanimate, all others (*конь, слон, король, ферзь*) are animate.

> А во множественном числе с числительным? Как правильно: потерять два ферзя или потерять двух ферзей? Потерять две пешки/ладьи или потерять двух пешек/ладей?

It's *потерять двух ферзей, потерять две пешки*.

*потерять два ферзя* is sometimes used colloquially as well.

Rosenthal et al., 153.3:

> В вариантах *купить двух коров – купить две коровы, подстрелить трех уток – подстрелить три утки* (при названиях животных в форме женского рода, когда речь идет об общем счете, купле-продаже) вторая форма имеет разговорный характер.

This makes numerals with plural genitive a bad test for animacy. Using an adjective or a possessive pronoun would make a better test: *потерял своих ферзей / *потерял свои ферзи; потерял свои пешки / *потерял своих пешек*

Also note that animacy is not an intrinsic property of a Russian noun, it can change with context: *изучать креветок / варить креветки*. Let me quote another piece from Rosenthal's guide:

> В различии форм *поймал трех рыбок – съел три рыбки* сказывается то обстоятельство, что во втором случае имеется в виду кушанье, т.е. неодушевленность (ср.: *съесть кильки, сардины, шпроты* – как нерасчлененный продукт; но: *съесть карасей, раков, цыплят* – как единичные предметы). Возможные варианты: *есть креветок, устриц, пулярок – есть креветки, устрицы, пулярки*. **Такие же колебания наблюдаются у существительных *матрешка, кукла, марионетка***.

(emphasis mine)

Chess pieces are not that unlike dolls or puppets, so I would not be surprised to hear something like *он делает шахматные короли и ферзи на токарном станке* some day, although this is ungrammatical as of now.

Comment: Also ladya here is a specific kind of ship or even kitchenware shaped after that ship, so it would weird for it to become animate. Whit peshka clearly somehow derived from peshekhod et al it should had been animate though. This thing is weird.

Comment: Пешка might be derived from пехотинец or пехота or just пеший.

Comment: @user31264 those all would imply being animated, right? Reportedly there was also пех, a leg that does not end with hoof. Those hoofed legs were нога (ноготь)