# How to decline animate neuter nouns in the accusative case?

Tags: склонение

How to say things like:

> Я вижу... дитя, лицо (в значении "человек"), животное, насекомое, млекопитающее, существо ("живой организм"), чудище, чудовище, страшилище...

Do they stay the same or do we need to change them?

Comment: How about words like: мертвец, покойник.... They are dead.....but they seem to be treated as living....? Weird... :(

Comment: 'They are dead.....but they seem to be treated as living'. Yes. Я вижу мертвеца, покойника. But  'я вижу труп'. /// Я вижу страшных зомби, снеговика, красивых *кукол* и *матрёшек*. But 'Я вижу красивые *статуэтки* балерин и красивые *фигурки*  оловянных солдатиков.'  /// Я вижу шахматные фигуры: короля, ферзя (королеву), слона (офицера), коня. But 'я вижу белые ладьи и черные пешки.

Answer (score 3):

As you might know, the Accusative of masculine (second declension) nouns depends on animacy: it is the same as Genitive for animate nouns and Nominative for inanimate:

- вижу тигра, тигров (animate)
- вижу стол, столы (inanimate)

Neuter nouns follow the same rule in the plural:

- вижу животных, насекомых, чудищ, детей, лиц (animate)
- вижу облака, окна, лёгкие (inanimate)

However, in the singular, Accusative always equals Nominative for neuter nouns, regardless of animacy:

- вижу дитя, чадо, животное, чудище, лицо, облако, лёгкое.

When in doubt, double-check yourself using this online declension tool:

[https://morpher.ru?s=животное](https://morpher.ru?s=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)

Comment: I mistook ellipsis in the question as a placeholder for an adjective, I think your answer is not only better but actually, well, an answer, so I'm deleting mine  )

Comment: In addition to the answer, the old discussion that I meant in my comment:  [How should I inflect animate nouns when they are used to figuratively call inanimate objects, and vice versa?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19855/how-should-i-inflect-animate-nouns-when-they-are-used-to-figuratively-call-inani) and there are further related links there as well.