# Will an animate Russian noun still remain animate if used to denote an inanimate object?

Tags: одушевлённость

This may be a strange question for someone who's fluent in Russian, but we were never taught it in school, and I realized I have a problem. I'm not sure which variant to use. So I decided to ask my question here.

Suppose we have an animate noun. Let it be **пилигрим**. I know it's animate because when we put it into the plural, the accusative coincides with the genitive. Well, it's 2nd declension masculine gender (according to school grammar), so we can use the singular as well.

My question is: will it remain grammatically animate if used to denote something inanimate, e.g. a ship?

For example, "Пилигрим" was a ship from "Dick Sand, A Captain at Fifteen", a novel by Jules Verne.
So, if it's a ship, which sentence is correct:
**«Я вижу „Пилигрим“»**
or
**«Я вижу „Пилигрима“»**?
(And why?)

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/19855/how-should-i-inflect-animate-nouns-when-they-are-used-to-figuratively-call-inani

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Russian, animacy is not a purely syntactic property of a noun; it depends on its semantic context.

A classic example is the names of animals, which *tend* to be inanimate when they refer to them as food and animate otherwise: *варить креветки / изучать креветок*. Other examples are anthropomorphic entities like *кукла, марионетка, робот, ферзь* etc. which can also be both animate and inanimate depending on the context and author's preference. Other Slavic languages treat things like the names of mushrooms, dances and so on as animate in some contexts, too, which can spill over into Russian as well: *плясать гопака, играть камаринского* and similar.

There's no universally accepted, strictly codified rule as to when to use what, and the authors of style guides do recognize this variability:

Rosenthal et al., *Справочник по правописанию и стилистике*, 151.8:

> В условных названиях (например, в названиях судов) одушевленные существительные **могут** (*emphasis mine, Q.*) склоняться как неодушевленные, например: *Курсанты торопились на уходящий в плавание "Фаворит"; Производится посадка на "Седов"* (подобные формы присущи разговорному языку; в книжном, литературном языке перед условным названием обычно ставят слово, обозначающее родовое понятие: *посадка на теплоход "Седов"*).

Examples of animate usage:

> - Когда "Опричника" в родных кильблоках, установленных на какие-то огромные салазки, трактор-тягач по аппарели втаскивал в гигантское чрево Лёхиного самолета, казалось, что сказочный кит с распахнутой пастью заглатывает маленькую, робкую сардинку! *[В. Кунин, Иванов и Рабинович, или "Ай гоу ту Хайфа!" (1991)]*
> - — Ну, Комендант, иди-ка помоги нашим ребятам швартоваться на «Пилигрима». *[А. С. Грин. Комендант порта (1933)]*

Answer (score 3):

It would be treated as inanimate:

- Именно так поступил и Джеме Уэлдон, снаряжая в плавание "Пилигрим".
- Пришлось отказаться от надежды дополна нагрузить "Пилигрим".

Many ships bear people's names: "Крузенштерн", "Адмирал Нахимов".

There are town names like Красный Боец which are also inanimate: еду в Красный Боец.

Comment: Some words have variable animacy: кукла, робот, устрицы, бактерии.

Answer (score 1):

Я напишу, но мне кажется, что пример не совсем удачный, так как тут именно название.

Похожие вопросы обсуждались на русский язык СЕ. Как я понял, правило звучит так, что с использованием ряда родовых слов, вроде штат, поселок, возможно сюда же войдут слова вроде корабль, танкер и тп., в этом случае название или именование не склоняется: в штате Аризона, а не Аризоны и не Аризоне, в посёлке Подосиновики, а не в посёлке Подосиновиках, но в Подосиновиках, и в Аризоне. Так что: мачта на корабле "Пилигрим", но можно мачта на "Пилигриме", а можно и мачта на "Пилигрим". Тут зависит, от того, насколько слово новое, если оно существует в русском языке, то может и склоняться.

А есть слова вроде бы "родовые" но нет - в городе Москве. Хотя, поеду в город Москва... Хотя, если подумать, то "поеду в город Москва" скажет человек, который в ней не живет или не относит себя к ней, воспринимает Москву как объект, и не одушевляет. А житель Москвы или тот кто там бывает, скажет "поеду в Москву" без родового слова.

Я вижу "Пилигрим", но я схожу с "Пилигрима". "Пилигрим" меня привез в Москву - "Пилигрим" субъект действия? Поеду на "Пилигриме" - объект.

Есть еще такое: вижу два близнеца - вижу башни-близнецы, и вижу двух близнецов - вижу детей близнецов. Окончание меняется в зависимости объект это, то есть "что-то" или "кто-то" - что вижу или кого вижу. Хотя можно сказать: вижу - дети-близнецы, - разорвав глагольную связку и превратив детей-кто в понятие. В общем, не только согласование окончаний, но и синтаксис может отражать отношение к слову как к одушевленному, неодушевленному или понятию - которое вообще отвечает на вопрос "что это" и имеет средний род, независимо от числа или рода.